# Binding a computed property in a text input with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm using the answer from [Bindings Computed Property in Ember TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374203/bindings-computed-property-in-ember-textfield), but would like to have it expanded upon a bit.

Here's my template:

```
{{input id="dollars" name="dollars" value=formattedDollars class="form-control"}}
```

And in my controller:

```
formattedDollars: function(key, value) {
    var model = this.get('model');
    if(value) {
        //This is the setter--make sure the stored value is an integer
        model.set('dollars', +value.toString().replace(/[^\d]/, ""));
    } else {
        //This is the getter--return a formatted value
        return model.get('dollars').toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
}.property('model.dollars')
```

This works if I am setting `formattedDollars` outside of the text field (e.g. `model.incrementProperty('dollars', 10)`), but if I actually type within the text input, the value does not stay formatted.

I've tried also returning `value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")` in the setter, but this didn't work either. How can I make it so that typing within the `dollars` input field automatically formats the number?

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the value in both cases - when getting or setting the computed property.
So your code should be:

```js
formattedDollars: function(key, value) {
    var model = this.get('model');
    if(arguments.length > 1) {
        //This is the setter--make sure the stored value is an integer
        model.set('dollars', +value.toString().replace(/[^\d]/, ""));
    } 
    //This is the getter--return a formatted value
    return model.get('dollars').toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    
}.property('model.dollars')
```